# Viewport Background not transparent in rendered preview

Tags: cycles-render-engine, transparency

In *rendered* viewport mode, the background doesn't appear transparent, but black when switching **Transparent** on under *Film* using *Cycles*.

[image]

Usually, I see a checked background indicating transparency.

[image]

What have I done with this file?

[image]

Comment: Despite answering this, I suspect this is a bug which should be reported to http://developer.blender.org/

Comment: @RayMairlot Thank you, seeing as the file is about 1 Mb, I had generated some strange data, which I did not know about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not quite sure *why* this is happening, but disabling the *Background Images* checkbox in the *Properties* shelf will return the transparent display in the viewport.